# I want to fetch data from table and append column name code to the value as key value pair. How to achieve this in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like "486" for "8_length" column.

I want it as 8=486.

Comment: major overhaul of this question needed as well as code and/or sample data

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer here? You haven't even asked a question. I would urge you to read this and ask yourself if you would be to answer this with only the information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like following.

```
SELECT '8=' + CAST([8_length] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [8_length]
FROM [Your_Table]
```

**Note:** If the column type is already `VARCHAR`, in that case you don't need to use `CAST`